# Lists of words to memorize before reading Lingua Latina Per Se Ilustrata classified by type: nouns, verbs, adjectives, etc

Tags: vocabulary, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

I read that a good way to use LLPSI is by memorizing lists of words before going to the text. Does anyone know where these word list are?

Comment: At the end of each chapter is a list of the vocabulary included in the chapter; You could skip to the end of a chapter to learn them prior to reading, although I think it sort of defeats the intent of Ørberg's approach in that you learn them through context (not that I haven't had to look up some here and there when I wasn't totally sure).

Answer (score 6):

The best list to memorize before reading each chapter of *LLPSI* is this:

> 

Seriously, you heard wrong. The whole point of *Lingua Latina Per Se Illustrata* is to learn each word from context. It's called "[the natural method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_%C3%98rberg)" because it teaches Latin the way you learn your native language (just faster and more streamlined): from context, always from context, without translating, not even in your mind. Try it! You'll like it. It's easy. It's fun, even.

If you really want to memorize word lists,* you might consider a different text, one that's designed for that approach.

* <sub>Does anyone really want to memorize word lists??</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. I got this idea from a guide to succeeding in the Downing Method, which is the immersion method. It affirmed that first one should learn the main latin categories by "brute memorization" and then proceed to reading LLPSI